# Esconder menu ao clicar fora e sair em js

Tags: javascript, html

Como esconder ul ao clicar fora do menu ou passar o mouse fora do menu? Tentei mas não obtive sucesso.

```js
function aperfil(opthard){
 if(document.getElementById(opthard).style.display== "none"){
  document.getElementById(opthard).style.display = "block";}
  else {document.getElementById(opthard).style.display = "none"}
  
  
  }
```

```html
<ul class="menup">

             <li><a href="#"><img src="img/icones/perfil.png" width="27" height="22"  alt="" onClick="aperfil('perfil');"/></a>
                <ul id="perfil" style="display: none; border:1px solid #5589c4; background-color:#fff;">
                      <li><a href="/painel/alt_pass.php">Alterar Senha</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/painel/suporte.php">Suporte</a></li> 
                      <li><a href="?go=sair">Sair</a></li> 
                        </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: tente usar a função jquery `onmouseout` que representa que você retirou o mouse em cima do menu.

Comment: @Marconi fiz o seguinte eu add <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  e aumentei o script $(document).ready(function() {


$("#perfil").mouseout(function() {
document.getElementById('perfil').style.display = 'none';
});

}); correto?

Comment: Troque `mouseout` por `onmouseout`. Passe o mouse na imagem .http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

Comment: para mim ficou mais adequado <script>function aperfil(opthard){
 if(document.getElementById(opthard).style.display== "none"){
  document.getElementById(opthard).style.display = "block";}
    } 
  <!-- ocultar o menu se passar o mouse fora necessita de jquery.min-->
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#perfil").mouseover(function() {
document.getElementById('perfil').style.display = 'block';
});
$("#perfil").mouseout(function() {
document.getElementById('perfil').style.display = 'none';
});
});
        </script>

Comment: Conseguiu? Vou postar uma resposta, só pra pergunta não ficar vaga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui no [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover.) tem um bom exemplo.

Repare que ao passar o mouse em cima da imagem é chamada a função `bigImg`e quando retirado chama a função `normalImg`.

```js
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "64px";
    x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "32px";
    x.style.width = "32px";
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```